# Symfony2 - confused cache clear trying to write to pro_

Tags: symfony, console

My Symfony installation seems to have gotten confused somewhere (probably during a failed cache clear). It seems to think that the production cache folder should be called `pro_` instead of `prod`.

First, when I tried to run `$ php console cache:clear --env=prod` I got the error message:

```
[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
Cannot rename "...cache/pro_" to "...cache/pro_".
```

I'm running on a windows dev machine (so there are no file system permissions issues).

So, I tried deleting all of the `cache/*` files/folders manually and trying again. This time the cache:clear went through and produced a single `prod` folder. That folder has subfolders for annotations, assetic, doctrine, sessions and twig.

But when I open the prod front controller (e.g. `http://devsite/` in a browser) it fails with the message:

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: 
Failed opening required '...cache/pro_/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__AcmeDemoBundleEntityFoo.php' 
(include_path='blah, blah, blah') 
in ...\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 165
```

From the looks of this it's trying to access cache files in pro_ instead of prod (again).

Looking in the cache folder I can see that `__CG__AcmeDemoBundleEntityFoo.php` exists under cache\prod but there is now a pro_ folder with annotations and sessions sub-folders.

**What's going on and how do I make Symfony forget about `pro_` so it can go back to using `prod` for everything?**

I thought everything to do with the cache was stored under the cache folder... is there something else (somewhere) that's storing some reference to `pro_`? Or am I looking in the wrong place for the solution to this problem?

**Edit:** Done some more searching and `appProdProjectContainer.php` contains 16 references to `.../cache/pro_`. If I manually search and replace these to `.../cache/prod` the site works. But the next time I run `console cache:clear` it resets them back to `pro_`. Where could this errant behaviour be coming from?

**Edit2:** OK, I got to the bottom of this and have submitted a PR to the Symfony core to try and fix it. The problem was caused by our cache path containing '\' characters which were then escaped in the cache files and failing to match a search/replace command which was meant to clean them up.

Comment: As far as I know a "pro_" folder is created during cache clear/warmup. It's a temp folder which will be renamed as soon as the new cache is ready and the old one deleted.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I sort of had that figured out already, but what I don't know is why the production front controller is using 'pro_' as the 'live' cache folder and why Symfony is 'stuck' thinking that 'pro_' is the cache folder instead of 'prod'...

Comment: Perhaps there are any other caches in place here? Opcode cache? User cache? What about a composer update?

Comment: Already done composer update, but doesn't seem to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Symfony's handling of cache paths with back-slashes in them.

The short term workaround is to replace them with forward slashes.

Longer term there is a fix posted as https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/9184 which will be brought into the core code soon.

Answer (score 2):

```
app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup
composer dump-autoload -o
app/console cache:warmup --env=prod
```

Comment: Nice try, but still the same problem. I even tried restarting the web server in the middle of the sequence to make sure there's no APC cache or similar interfering.

Comment: tip: perform an in-file search for the string `pro_` on your whole project after warming your cache and inspect your findings.

Comment: The only references are in ``...cache\prod\appProdProjectContainer.php`` (see the edit above). When I had some time this morning I tried playing around with ``CacheClearCommand``'s source file but still not able to figure out what's going wrong or how to fix it. Thanks again for the suggestions, though!

Comment: could you please try `composer update -o` which will usually invoke ` Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap`. Please report back if this fixes your problem.

Comment: ok... some progress. After running this command the prod environment works. However, if I run ``console cache:clear --env=prod`` it breaks again, until I manually delete the folders in ``cache\pro_``and ``cache\prod``. Running ``console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup`` is now fine, though. So this is good enough for the dev machine. My curiosity still wants to get to the bottom of it, though!

Comment: Found the problem - we had a custom cache dir set in AppKernel::getCacheDir() which contained backslashes (on windows). When running ``console cache:clear`` the cache warmer escapes these when they're dumped into ``appProdProjectContainer`` so there are refernces to things like ``C:\\path\\to\\cache/pro_/annotations``. These are then missed by the part of ``CacheClearCommand::execute()`` labelled with the comment ``fix references to cached files with the real cache directory name``. I'll look into fixing this so it properly handles windows paths and submitting a PR to the Sf core.