# Twig tries to include file from temporary cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, twig

I can't reproduce this locally and it's confusing me a lot. As part of deployment to multiple servers we regularly get this error:

```
include_once(): Failed opening '/path/to/symfony/app/cache/prefix__pro_/twig/6e/af294156cb5dce4b373f578f4ef1c3e2d1d738daf1dbdf18476b1716a7f.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

It happens when we run the `app/console cache:clear` command in symfony.

The environment is `prod` and I learned that twig first creates a temporary cache folder (e.g. for `dev` it would be `cache/__de/twig`, for `prod` it's `cache/__pro/twig` etc) before renaming it to the real environment. I'm also confused why anything would be trying to access the temporary cache.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253281/symfony2-confused-cache-clear-trying-to-write-to-pro) question seems related but was resolved to be a problem with backslashes in cache path (which we don't have).

https://www.drupal.org/node/2429659 also seems to have the same problem, but I don't think our problem is due to our site is being visited during the cache clearing (during deployment it will warm up the cache on a a separately prepared codebase - not the real production code). It also links to a PHP bug where two threads trying to create a directory will fail, but I don't think more than one thread is involved here.

Comment: Opcache settings maybe?

Comment: We are having the same error popping up after updates. Did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: I just checked with my old boss and we ended up ignoring this. The problem is discussed [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1836). We couldn't find any nice way to handle it. The code in question is using `@fopen` which suppresses the error but still logs it, so you might just want to add some logic to ignore these errors in your logger. I don't think it was causing any problems, just annoying to get the logs repeatedly.